# WMMouseWheel not working in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I wrote the following code:
`procedure MouseWheel(var Msg:TWMMouseWheel);message WM_MOUSEHWHEEL;`
I used it for a component based on TPanel (TMyP=class(TPanel))
(Notice that I don't want to use TCustomPanel due to my own reasons)

But anyway the event is not called when I use mouse wheel on the panel.
Please Help me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297234/tlistview-and-mouse-wheel-scrolling

Comment: See [How to add mouse wheel support to a component descended from TGraphicControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34463279/757830), and [How to direct the mouse wheel input to control under cursor instead of focused?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34386680/757830)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mouse wheel messages are sent to the control with the focus. And panels usually aren't focusable.

I use this TApplicationEvents.OnMessage handler in my applications to send the mouse wheel message to the window under the mouse cursor instead of the focused control.

```
procedure TMainDataModule.ApplicationEventsMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Wnd: HWND;
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEWHEEL then
  begin
    Wnd := WindowFromPoint(Msg.pt);
    // It must be a VCL control otherwise we could get access violations
    if IsVCLControl(Wnd) then
      Msg.hwnd := Wnd; // change the message receiver to the control under the cursor
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I wonder if this doesn't break consistent user experience, where the user is used to have mouse wheel messages going to the focused control and apparently in your application they go somewhere else.

Comment: Actually this was a user request brought to me by our product management.

Comment: I tried this in C++ Builder but it doesn't work. I also tried a couple of variants similar to this but none worked. I guess it works in Delphi but not in C++ Builder. I also checked for WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL but no effect. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Andreas Hausladen's answer you need to know, that some mouse drivers don't send WM_MOUSEWHEEL and instead send several WM_VSCROLL messages. You need to check this as well.

Upd: Note, that there exist also WM_HSCROLL messages which can also be sent by some mice which have two wheels or a tilting wheel. That's why I wrote WM_SCROLL initially.

Comment: Thnx for the answer but i can't find WM_SCROLL

Comment: It's actually WM_VSCROLL (vertical scroll).