# TListView and mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, delphi-xe

I have a TListView component in a form. It's quite long and I want user to able scroll it, if mouse is over the component and wheel is scrolled. I do not find any OnMouseWheel, OnMouseWheelDown or OnMouseWheelUp event for TListView object. How can I do that?

Regards,
evilone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my code to do this:

```
type
  TMyListView = class(TListView)
  protected
    function DoMouseWheelDown(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
    function DoMouseWheelUp(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
  end;

type    
  TMouseWheelDirection = (mwdUp, mwdDown);

function GenericMouseWheel(Handle: HWND; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDirection: TMouseWheelDirection): Boolean;
var
  i, ScrollCount, Direction: Integer;
  Paging: Boolean;
begin
  Result := ModifierKeyState(Shift)=[];//only respond to un-modified wheel actions
  if Result then begin
    Paging := DWORD(Mouse.WheelScrollLines)=WHEEL_PAGESCROLL;
    ScrollCount := Mouse.WheelScrollLines;
    case WheelDirection of
    mwdUp:
      if Paging then begin
        Direction := SB_PAGEUP;
        ScrollCount := 1;
      end else begin
        Direction := SB_LINEUP;
      end;
    mwdDown:
      if Paging then begin
        Direction := SB_PAGEDOWN;
        ScrollCount := 1;
      end else begin
        Direction := SB_LINEDOWN;
      end;
    end;
    for i := 1 to ScrollCount do begin
      SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, Direction, 0);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TMyListView.DoMouseWheelDown(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  //don't call inherited
  Result := GenericMouseWheel(Handle, Shift, mwdDown);
end;

function TMyListView.DoMouseWheelUp(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  //don't call inherited
  Result := GenericMouseWheel(Handle, Shift, mwdUp);
end;
```

`GenericMouseWheel` is quite nifty. It works for any control with a vertical scroll bar. I use it with tree views, list views, list boxes, memos, rich edits, etc.

You'll be missing my `ModifierKeyState` routine but you can substitute your own method for checking that the wheel event is not modified. The reason you want to do this is the, for example, CTRL+mouse wheel means zoom rather than scroll.

For what it's worth, it looks like this:

```
type
  TModifierKey = ssShift..ssCtrl;
  TModifierKeyState = set of TModifierKey;

function ModifierKeyState(Shift: TShiftState): TModifierKeyState;
const
  AllModifierKeys = [low(TModifierKey)..high(TModifierKey)];
begin
  Result := AllModifierKeys*Shift;
end;
```

Comment: Is that enough? I thought wheel messages don't always go to the window under cursor, they go to the top level window (Delphi form); So the list view isn't always receiving them. I know I had to do a lot of message-forwarding for a project hat needed wheel messages in a Frame.

Comment: @David, in my project I was trying to handle the WM_MOUSEHWHEEL directly, and the message didn't flow properly (I'd sometimes get it on the frame, sometimes on the form, sometimes on both the frame and the form). It took me 5 minutes to figure out others faced this problem and an an other 5 minutes to develop my hack. Now reading the code in `TControl.WndProc()` I finally figured it out: The wheel message is not necessary WM_MOUSEWHEEL (because WM_MOUSEWHEEL is equal to WM_MOUSELAST). That's why (a) I didn't always get the message and (b) I sometimes got the message twice. Thanks and +1.

Comment: @Cosmin This is a really neat solution and it highlights some genius in the design of Win32 in that the same messages work for any scrollable control.

Comment: @David, I was thinking it's more of a hack to accommodate the late introduction of mouse wheel processing in the operating system itself (remember the times when each mouse driver implemented scrolling however it felt appropriate).

Comment: @Cosmin The fact that scroll messages work in every different control type was there right from Windows 1.0. DefWindowProc gives implementation inheritance. Quite well thought out considering it was released in 1985.

Comment: @David, those scrollable controls were designed to accommodate the page up / page down buttons on the keyboard, and that doesn't explain why the mouse wheel doesn't have it's own message.

Comment: @Cosmin Mouse wheel was invented later as you have said. Yes it was a real pain in the early days when the message wheel messages did not exist. My point is that the good design of WM_VSCROLL and DefWindowProc etc. made the solution I posted possible. That's all.

Comment: @David, I was trying to point out a different problem, because that's what got me in trouble. Sure, WM_VSCROLL is nicely implemented, but WM_MOUSEHWHEEL is not equally well implemented (or I'm not understanding it properly). Your solution works not only because of WM_VSCROLL, but also because `Delphi` implemented a good hack for the strange WM_MOUSEWHEEL in `TControl.WndProc`.

Comment: @Cosmin Yes, agreed, some aspects of Win32 are genius, and some aspects less than genius!