# Need example for for WM_MouseWheel

Tags: delphi

My control(Like TMemo) has not MouseWheel code. How to add correct Wheel handler so it scrolls correct Num of lines - if ControlPanel has set 3 lines per rotate, I need 3 lines to scroll by one rotate.

My test is

```
procedure TMyMemo.WMMouseWheel(var Message: TWMMouseWheel); 
var
  Delta: Integer;
begin
  Delta:= Message.WheelDelta div 80 * Mouse.WheelScrollLines;//??????
  ScrollPosY := ScrollPosY - Delta;
  Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

I don't think `80` is ok, it's guessed- it works here (with Win7). How to get correct Num of lines to scroll?

Comment: It won't help, TLama. I need to get correct Delphi code which gets OK num of lines for current PC.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question? Why didn't you edit it? So that the comments weren't lost. What a waste of effort. -1

Comment: Because comment shows that questiuon was bad, I rewrote it.

Comment: Please edit questions rather than delete and post again. The history has value. Much of what I commented on there has not been addressed here.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297234/tlistview-and-mouse-wheel-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

I found OK way. I need to write `Protected` methods:

```
DoMouseWheelUp.....; override;
DoMouseWheelDown......; override;
```

and in each, I must scroll by Delta=`Mouse.WheelScrollLines`.