# Handle mouse wheel event with shift key pressed

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to implement horizontal scrolling if the mouse wheel is used while the `Shift`key is pressed. But I do not get any `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages in this case:

```
procedure WMMouseWheel(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_MOUSEWHEEL;  // is not called
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms645617(v=vs.85).aspx), there should be a `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message with `MK_SHIFT` WPARAM.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a lot of information at: [How to direct the mouse wheel input to control under cursor instead of focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386680/757830) and [How to add mouse wheel support to a component descended from TGraphicControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463279/757830).

Answer (score 6):

Edit: the following code uses WM_MOUSE**H**WHEEL, not WM_MOUSEWHEEL to handle horizontal scrolling.

I find this code in my code base:

```
procedure TMyScrollBox.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg=WM_MOUSEHWHEEL then begin
    (* For some reason using a message handler for WM_MOUSEHWHEEL doesn't work.
       The messages don't always arrive. It seems to occur when both scroll bars
       are active. Strangely, if we handle the message here, then the messages
       all get through. Go figure! *)
    if TWMMouseWheel(Message).Keys=0 then begin
      HorzScrollBar.Position := HorzScrollBar.Position + TWMMouseWheel(Message).WheelDelta;
      Message.Result := 0;
    end else begin
      Message.Result := 1;
    end;
  end else begin
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

So, there you have it. I don't understand why this is so, but you should be able to do the same as I do, and override `WndProc` to process this message.