# How to "catch" onMouseWheel-Event inside a custom component

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I am quite new to Delphi and wanted to practise a little bit.

While trying to implement a basic custom component I couldn't figure out how to "catch" events like "OnMouseWheel" or "OnMouseMove" etc..
(the component just should let the user zoom into an TImage)

At the moment I wrote some public functions like LMouseWheel(...), now the user of the component has to implement the OnMouseWheel-Function, but only has to call the public MouseWheel(...)-Method to get the component working. Is there a way, that the MouseWheel-Method gets called by default?

The code is an abstract of my custom component. What do I have to do, to immediately call the LMouseWheel(...)-Method, when the user scrolls the mouse wheel over my component?

```pascal
unit TLZoomage;

{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE Delphi}
{$ENDIF}
interface

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, LCLType, Controls, Graphics,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, Spin, Types, Math;

type

  { TLZoomage }

  TLZoomage = class(TImage)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FStartZoom: integer;
    FmaxZoom: integer;
    FminZoom: integer;
    FcurrentZoom: integer;
    FzoomSpeed: integer;

    mouseMoveOrigin: TPoint;

    procedure setCurrentZoom(AValue: integer);
    procedure setMaxZoom(AValue: integer);
    procedure setMinZoom(AValue: integer);
    procedure setStartZoom(AValue: integer);
  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }
    property currentZoom: integer read FcurrentZoom write setCurrentZoom;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

    //###################################################################
    //###################################################################
    //
    // This should get called automatically
    //
    //###################################################################
    //###################################################################
    procedure LMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: integer; MousePos: TPoint; var  Handled: boolean);

  published
    property maxZoom: integer read FmaxZoom write setMaxZoom;
    property minZoom: integer read FminZoom write setMinZoom;
    property startZoom: integer read FStartZoom write setStartZoom;
    property zoomSpeed: integer read FzoomSpeed write FzoomSpeed;
  end;

{$ENDIF}
procedure Register;

implementation

{$IFnDEF MSWINDOWS}
procedure Register;
begin

end;

{$ELSE}
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('test', [TLZoomage]);
end;

{ TLZoomage }

//###################################################################
//###################################################################
//
// This should get called automatically
//
//###################################################################
//###################################################################
procedure TLZoomage.LMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: boolean);
var
  xZoomPoint: double;
  yZoomPoint: double;
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) then
  begin
    xZoomPoint := MousePos.x / self.Width;
    yZoomPoint := MousePos.y / self.Height;
    // der Benutzer möchte zoomen
    currentZoom := currentZoom + Sign(WheelDelta) * scrollSpeed;

    self.Left := round(self.Left + MousePos.x - (xZoomPoint * self.Width));
    self.Top := round(self.Top + MousePos.y - (yZoomPoint * self.Height));
  end;
  Handled:=true;
end;

procedure TLZoomage.setCurrentZoom(AValue: integer);
var
  ChildScaleFactor: double;
  ParentScaleFactor: double;
begin
  FcurrentZoom := AValue;
  if (FcurrentZoom < minZoom) then
    FcurrentZoom := minZoom;
  if (FcurrentZoom > maxZoom) then
    FcurrentZoom := maxZoom;
  if Assigned(self.Picture) then
  begin
    self.Width := round(self.Picture.Width * FcurrentZoom / 100);
    self.Height := round(self.Picture.Height * FcurrentZoom / 100);
    if Assigned(self.Parent) then
    begin
      if (self.Width < self.Parent.Width) and (self.Height < self.Parent.Height) and
        (self.Height <> 0) then
      begin
        ChildScaleFactor := self.Width / self.Height;
        ParentScaleFactor := self.Parent.Width / self.Parent.Height;
        // Parent ist breiter -> Höhe gibt die größe vor
        if (ParentScaleFactor > ChildScaleFactor) then
        begin
          self.Height := self.Parent.Height;
          self.Width := round(ChildScaleFactor * self.Parent.Height);
        end
        else
          // Parent ist höher -> Breite gibt die Größe vor
        begin
          self.Width := self.Parent.Width;
          self.Height := round(self.Parent.Width / ChildScaleFactor);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TLZoomage.setMaxZoom(AValue: integer);
begin
  FmaxZoom := AValue;
  currentZoom := currentZoom;
end;

procedure TLZoomage.setMinZoom(AValue: integer);
begin
  FminZoom := AValue;
  currentZoom := currentZoom;
end;

procedure TLZoomage.setStartZoom(AValue: integer);
begin
  currentZoom := AValue;
  FstartZoom := currentZoom;
end;

procedure TLZoomage.limitImgPos();
begin
  if Assigned(self.Parent) then
  begin
  // limit the Scrolling
  if self.Left > 0 then
    self.Left := 0;
  if self.Left < -(self.Width - self.Parent.Width) then
    self.Left := -(self.Width - self.Parent.Width);

  if self.Top > 0 then
    self.Top := 0;
  if self.Top < -(self.Height - self.Parent.Height) then
    self.Top := -(self.Height - self.Parent.Height);

  end;
end;

constructor TLZoomage.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  maxZoom := 200;
  minZoom := 10;
  startZoom := 100;
  FzoomSpeed := 10;
  currentZoom := startZoom;
end;

{$ENDIF}

end.
```

Solution:
The simplest solution was, to override the following procedure / functions out of TControl, thanks to "Remy Lebeau":

```pascal
function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift:TShiftState; X,Y:Integer); override;
procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X,Y: Integer); override;
procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift:TShiftState; X,Y:Integer); override;
```

Comment: Use a windowed control.

Comment: Indeed, `TImage` is based off of `TGraphicControl` which does not have a window handle. If you need to display an image only, simply draw it onto your control canvas. No need to inherit from a ready-made control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi's VCL `TControl` has virtual `DoMouseWheel(Down|Up)()` and `Mouse(Down|Move|Up)()` methods that your component can `override` as needed:

```
function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; dynamic;
function DoMouseWheelDown(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; dynamic;
function DoMouseWheelUp(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; dynamic;
...
procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); dynamic;
procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); dynamic;
procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); dynamic;
```

Delphi's FMX `TControl` has virtual `Mouse(Down|Move|Up|Wheel)()` methods:

```
procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single); virtual;
procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single); virtual;
procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);  virtual;
procedure MouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean); virtual;
```

FreePascal's `TControl` has virtual `Mouse(Down|Move|Up)()` and `DoMouseWheel(Down|Up)()` methods that mirror VCL,  as well as additional virtual `DoMouseWheel(Horz|Left|Right)` methods:

```
procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); virtual;
procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); virtual;
procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); virtual;
...
function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; virtual;
function DoMouseWheelDown(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; virtual;
function DoMouseWheelUp(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; virtual;
function DoMouseWheelHorz(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; virtual;
function DoMouseWheelLeft(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; virtual;
function DoMouseWheelRight(Shift: TShiftState; MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; virtual;
```

In all cases, the framework handles catching the actual mouse events from the OS and then calls the per-component virtual methods automatically as needed.  This works even for graphical controls, as a parent windowed control will detect mouse activity over a graphical child control and delegate accordingly.

**UPDATE**: in the case of Delphi's VCL `TControl` (not sure about Delphi's FMX `TControl`, or FreePascal's `TControl`), delegation of mouse *clicks* works as expected, but delegation of mouse *wheel* movements does not.  You have to take some extra steps to receive mouse wheel notifications in a graphical control:

[How to add mouse wheel support to a component descended from TGraphicControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456488/)

Comment: - *This works even for graphical controls, ...* - Not in VCL of XE2, later versions perhaps?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz AFAIK, it works in *all* versions, and always has. If there is a particular *bug* in XE2, that is a different issue than how the *interface* is designed. Components are intended to override the virtual methods, and they exist in `TControl` instead of `TWinControl` so that graphical and windowed controls can leverage them equally. A recent system failure (of my XE2 system, of all things) required me to get a new computer, and I haven't installed the IDE onto it yet, so I can't test this for myself at the moment.

Comment: I don't see any delegation code in XE2. If a wincontrol does not handle a wheel message it passes it to it's parent. And there it remains. Now tested with D2007 too, same...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz you are right: [How to add mouse wheel support to a component descended from TGraphicControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456488/).  I updated my answer.