# Why my Control does not catch MouseWheel messages?

Tags: controls, c++builder, c++builder-2006

**Using C++Builder 2006.**

I'm trying to modify a TCustomControl derived class, and i need that class to catch mouse wheel events (or messages).
I've tried to use the answer for [this Delphi question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456488/how-to-add-mouse-wheel-support-to-a-component-descended-from-tgraphiccontrol) but i don't get the event.

This is my relevant code:

**TMouseWheelHandler.h**

```
class PACKAGE TMouseWheelHandler : public TCustomControl
{
private:
  typedef TCustomControl inherited;

protected:
  virtual void __fastcall Paint();

  void __fastcall WMSize            (TWMSize &Message);
  void __fastcall CMMouseEnter  (TMessage &Message);
  void __fastcall CMMouseLeave  (TMessage &Message);
  void __fastcall WMMouseMove       (TMessage &Message);
  BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, TWMSize, WMSize)
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSEENTER   , TMessage, CMMouseEnter)
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSELEAVE   , TMessage, CMMouseLeave)
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_MOUSEMOVE    , TMessage, WMMouseMove)
  END_MESSAGE_MAP(TCustomControl)

  virtual bool DoMouseWheel     (TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint & MousePos);
  virtual bool DoMouseWheelDown (TShiftState Shift,                 TPoint & MousePos);
  virtual bool DoMouseWheelUp       (TShiftState Shift,                 TPoint & MousePos);
  void MouseWheelHandler    (const TMessage &Message);

public:
  __fastcall TMouseWheelHandler(TComponent* Owner);

__published:
  __property OnMouseWheelUp;
  __property OnMouseWheelDown;
  __property OnMouseWheel;
  __property OnClick;
};
```

**TMouseWheelHandler.cpp**

```
//===========================================================================
//===========================================================================
//===========================================================================
bool TMouseWheelHandler::DoMouseWheel   (TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint & MousePos)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
  return inherited::DoMouseWheel(Shift,WheelDelta,MousePos);
}
//===========================================================================
bool TMouseWheelHandler::DoMouseWheelDown (TShiftState Shift,         TPoint & MousePos)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
  return inherited::DoMouseWheelDown(Shift, MousePos);
}
//===========================================================================
bool TMouseWheelHandler::DoMouseWheelUp   (TShiftState Shift,         TPoint & MousePos)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
  return inherited::DoMouseWheelUp(Shift, MousePos);
}
//===========================================================================
// MOUSE MANAGEMENT TAKEN FROM STACKOVERFLOW DELPHI SOLUTION
//===========================================================================
void __fastcall TMouseWheelHandler::CMMouseEnter  (TMessage &Message)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
  SetFocus();
  MouseCapture = true;
  Refresh();
}
//===========================================================================
void __fastcall TMouseWheelHandler::CMMouseLeave  (TMessage &Message)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
  MouseCapture = false;
  Refresh();
}
//===========================================================================
void __fastcall TMouseWheelHandler::WMMouseMove (TMessage &Message)
{
  if (MouseCapture) {
    TPoint pt;
    POINTSTOPOINT(pt , MAKEPOINTS(Message.LParam) );

    if (PtInRect(ClientRect, pt) ) {
      OutputDebugString("MOUSE IN");
    }else{
      OutputDebugString("MOUSE OUT");
      MouseCapture = false;
      Refresh();
    }
  }else{
    OutputDebugString("NO_CAPTURE");
  }
}
//===========================================================================
void TMouseWheelHandler::MouseWheelHandler  (const TMessage &Message)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
  TMessage MyMessage = Message; // In the DELPHI sample Message was'nt a const
  MyMessage.Result = Perform(CM_MOUSEWHEEL, MyMessage.WParam, MyMessage.LParam);
  if (MyMessage.Result == 0) {
    inherited::MouseWheelHandler(MyMessage);
  }
}
//===========================================================================
//===========================================================================
//===========================================================================
```

And this is how i use the Control in my Form:

```
WH = new TMouseWheelHandler(this);
WH->Parent = Panel1;
WH->Align  = alTop;
WH->Height = Panel1->Height/2;
WH->OnMouseWheel        = GGMouseWheel;
WH->OnMouseWheelDown    = GGMouseWheelDown;
WH->OnMouseWheelUp      = GGMouseWheelUp;

void __fastcall TTestForm::GGMouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, const TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TTestForm::GGMouseWheelDown(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, const TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TTestForm::GGMouseWheelUp(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, const TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
  OutputDebugString(__FUNC__);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What i see from the debug prints are that none of the *DoMouse** functions and also the *MouseWheelHandler* function are never called, while the Form *GGMouseWheel** functions are.

All i'd need is to manage some variables in the DoMouse* functions.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MESSAGE_MAP` should be declared `public` not `protected`, since it overrides the virtual `Dispatch()` method which is `public`. Personally, I prefer to override the virtual `WndProc()` method instead of using `MESSAGE_MAP`s.

That being said, there is no need to handle the mouse wheel messages directly, simply override the virtual `DoMouseWheel...()` methods. Note that your `DoMouseWheel...()` and `MouseWheelHandler()` methods are all declared incorrectly, so they are NOT overriding the virtual methods of the same names.

Try these declarations instead (you could have looked in `Controls.hpp` to get these, or read the documentation):

```cpp
DYNAMIC bool __fastcall DoMouseWheel(TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, const TPoint &MousePos);
DYNAMIC bool __fastcall DoMouseWheelDown(TShiftState Shift, const TPoint &MousePos);
DYNAMIC bool __fastcall DoMouseWheelUp(TShiftState Shift, const TPoint &MousePos);
DYNAMIC void __fastcall MouseWheelHandler(TMessage &Message);
```